# SQL Help : Update a field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables course and course1 
Both the tables have  fields called name and id.
Table course's id field is currently null. I need to update course table's id field with id of the course1, both tables are related with name field.

I am using access.

Thanks

Prady

Comment: "Name" and "ID" are both really bad names for fields, the first because it's a reserved word, and the second because if you use it multiple tables, you're going to have namespace collisions any time you need the IDs from more than one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update [course 1]
inner join [course]
on course.name = [course 1].name
set [course 1].ID = [course].ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1 set id = b.id from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.name = b.name
```

This works on SQL Server. I haven't tried on Access but give it a try.